Why does Host-based Card Emulation not work with newer Android versions?
I would like to emulate a Type 4 Tag with a simple NDEF message and read it with another phone. My code is basically from https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid, I did only a few modifications like changing the maximum NDEF file size to 7FFF, as this was a problem in the past.
I have 4 devices for testing, each has a different Android version: Android 8, 11, 12 and 14. HCE works on Android 8 and 11, but not on 12 and 14. Through the logs I can see that the HCEService is started successfully, but the method processCommandApdu is never called. On Android 8 and 11 everything works fine and the method is called normally.
For reading I always used the respective other phones. Is it maybe not allowed anymore to emulate a Type 4 Tag (AID D2760000850101)?
My Code:
class HCEService : HostApduService() {

    private val TAG = "HostApduService"

    private val APDU_SELECT = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xA4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x04.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x07.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xD2.toByte(),
        0x76.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x85.toByte(),
        0x01.toByte(),
        0x01.toByte(), // NDEF Tag Application name
        0x00.toByte(), // Le field  - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
    )

    private val CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xa4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x0c.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xe1.toByte(),
        0x03.toByte(), // file identifier of the CC file
    )

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xb0.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x0f.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    )

    // In the scenario that we have done a CC read, the same byte[] match
    // for ReadBinary would trigger and we don't want that in succession
    private var READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), 0x11.toByte(), // CCLEN length of the CC file
        0x20.toByte(), // Mapping Version 2.0
        0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLe maximum
        0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLc maximum
        0x04.toByte(), // T field of the NDEF File Control TLV
        0x06.toByte(), // L field of the NDEF File Control TLV
        0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), // File Identifier of NDEF file
        0x7F.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // Maximum NDEF file size of 65534 bytes
        0x00.toByte(), // Read access without any security
        0xFF.toByte(), // Write access without any security
        0x90.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), // A_OKAY
    )

    private val NDEF_SELECT_OK = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xa4.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
        0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
        0x0c.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
        0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xE1.toByte(),
        0x04.toByte(), // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
        0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
        0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
        0x02.toByte(), // Le field
    )

    private val A_OKAY = byteArrayOf(
        0x90.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
        0x00.toByte(), // SW2   Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val A_ERROR = byteArrayOf(
        0x6A.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
        0x82.toByte(), // SW2   Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val NDEF_ID = byteArrayOf(0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte())

    private var NDEF_URI = NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", "Ciao, come va?", NDEF_ID))
    private var NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
    private var NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
        BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(),
        2,
    )

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent?.hasExtra("ndefMessage")!!) {
            NDEF_URI =
                NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage")!!, NDEF_ID))

            NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
            NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
                BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(),
                2,
            )
        }
        Log.i(TAG, intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage")!!)

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() | NDEF$NDEF_URI")

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray {
        //
        // The following flow is based on Appendix E "Example of Mapping Version 2.0 Command Flow"
        // in the NFC Forum specification
        //
        Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: " + commandApdu.toHex())

        //
        // First command: NDEF Tag Application select (Section 5.5.2 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (APDU_SELECT.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Second command: Capability Container select (Section 5.5.3 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Third command: ReadBinary data from CC file (Section 5.5.4 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER.contentEquals(commandApdu) && !READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK
        ) {
            Log.i(
                TAG,
                "READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE.toHex(),
            )
            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = true
            return READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE
        }

        //
        // Fourth command: NDEF Select command (Section 5.5.5 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (NDEF_SELECT_OK.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_SELECT_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        if (NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
            // Build our response
            val response = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + A_OKAY.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, NDEF_URI_LEN.size, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        if (commandApdu.size > 1 &&  commandApdu.sliceArray(0..1).contentEquals(NDEF_READ_BINARY)) {
            val offset = commandApdu.sliceArray(2..3).toHex().toInt(16)
            val length = commandApdu.sliceArray(4..4).toHex().toInt(16)

            val fullResponse = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + NDEF_URI_BYTES.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, fullResponse, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(
                NDEF_URI_BYTES,
                0,
                fullResponse,
                NDEF_URI_LEN.size,
                NDEF_URI_BYTES.size,
            )

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Full data: " + fullResponse.toHex())
            Log.i(TAG, "READ_BINARY - OFFSET: $offset - LEN: $length")

            val slicedResponse = fullResponse.sliceArray(offset until fullResponse.size)

            // Build our response
            val realLength = if (slicedResponse.size <= length) slicedResponse.size else length
            val response = ByteArray(realLength + A_OKAY.size)

            System.arraycopy(slicedResponse, 0, response, 0, realLength)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, realLength, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        //
        // We're doing something outside our scope
        //
        Log.wtf(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | I don't know what's going on!!!")
        return A_ERROR
    }

    override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: $reason")
    }

    private val HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()

    private fun ByteArray.toHex(): String {
        val result = StringBuffer()

        forEach {
            val octet = it.toInt()
            val firstIndex = (octet and 0xF0).ushr(4)
            val secondIndex = octet and 0x0F
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[firstIndex])
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[secondIndex])
        }

        return result.toString()
    }

    private fun createTextRecord(language: String, text: String, id: ByteArray): NdefRecord {
        val languageBytes: ByteArray
        val textBytes: ByteArray
        try {
            languageBytes = language.toByteArray(charset("US-ASCII"))
            textBytes = text.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            throw AssertionError(e)
        }

        val recordPayload = ByteArray(1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F) + textBytes.size)

        recordPayload[0] = (languageBytes.size and 0x03F).toByte()
        System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1, languageBytes.size and 0x03F)
        System.arraycopy(
            textBytes,
            0,
            recordPayload,
            1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F),
            textBytes.size,
        )

        return NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, id, recordPayload)
    }

    private fun fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(array: ByteArray, fixedSize: Int): ByteArray {
        if (array.size == fixedSize) {
            return array
        }

        val start = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte())
        val filledArray = ByteArray(start.size + array.size)
        System.arraycopy(start, 0, filledArray, 0, start.size)
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, filledArray, start.size, array.size)
        return fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(filledArray, fixedSize)
    }
}

apduservice.xml:
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:category="other"
        android:description="@string/app_name">
        <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101" />
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>

AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFContact"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        ...

        <service
            android:name="com.example.nfcontact.service.HCEService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>

I went through nearly all HCE questions on StackOverflow and found no fix for this. I would be grateful for every help.
